# How to create links with GET parameter

Tags: javascript, php, url, hyperlink, get

I am trying to create custom links for all the individuals in a page. Each individual has a separate id. How can I create the links using `GET` parameter. The data is being pulled using JSON

**Javascript**

```
$.getInfo = function() {
    var selected_reference_id = $.cookie("selected_reference_id");
    $.ajax({
        url: "assets/functions/editor.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {selected_reference_id: selected_reference_id},
        success: function(data) {
            var json_data = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(json_data);
            console.log(json_data[0].profile_image_url);
            $("#editor_name").html(json_data[0].name);
            $("#profile_description").html(json_data[0].profile_description);
            $("#profile_picture").html('<img alt="" id="profile_picture" src="' + json_data[0].profile_image_url + '" class="member-img">');
            $("#main_video").html('<video id="MY_VIDEO_0" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls \n\
                                       preload="none" width="640" height="264" poster="' + json_data[0].thumbnail_url + '"\n\
                                       data-setup="{}">\n\
                                        <source src="' + json_data[0].video_url + '" type="video/mp4">\n\
                                        <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>\n\
                                    </video>');
            $("#editor_tags").append(json_data[0].is_sports);
            $("#editor_tags").append(json_data[0].is_weddings);
            $("#editor_tags").append(json_data[0].is_travel);
            $("#editor_tags").append(json_data[0].is_everyday_moments);
            $("#editor_tags").append(json_data[0].is_special_occasions);
            $("#editor_tags").append(json_data[0].is_motion_graphics);
            $("#editor_tags").append(json_data[0].is_promo);
            $("#editor_tags").append(json_data[0].is_tutorials);
            $("#editor_tags").append(json_data[0].is_crowdfunding);
            $("#editor_tags").append(json_data[0].is_collage);

            $.each(json_data, function(index) {
                //console.log(data[index].email);
                var addRow = '<li class="mix all" style="margin-bottom: 6px;"><video id="MY_VIDEO_' + index + '"  class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls \n\
                                       preload="none" width="100%" height="264" poster="' + json_data[index].thumbnail_url + '"\n\
                                       data-setup="{}">\n\
                                        <source src="' + json_data[index].video_url + '" type="video/mp4">\n\
                                        <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>\n\
                                    </video></li>';
//                var addRow = '<li class="mix webdesign">\n\
//                            <!-- <img src="themes/demo/assets/dream/images/work/thumbnail-01.jpg" alt=""/> -->\n\
//                            <video style="width: 100%; height: 100%" controls>\n\
//                                <source src="' + json_data[index].video_url + '" type="video/mp4">\n\
//                                <source src="' + json_data[index].video_url + '" type="video/ogg">\n\
//                            </video>\n\
//                        </li>';
                if (index !== 0) {
                    $("#work-preview").append(addRow);
                }

            });




//            $("#main_video").html('<video style="width: 40%; height: 40%" class="video" controls>\n\
//                                                    <source src="'+json_data[0].video_url+'" type="video/mp4">\n\
//                                                    <source src="'+json_data[0].video_url+'" type="video/ogg">\n\
//                                                </video>');
//            if (json_reserve.alreadyReserved === 0) {
//                $("#upload_row").show();
//                $.timer(json_question[0].timeleft);
//            } else {
//                $.dialogAlreadyReserved(); //a function I defined to pop up a dialog
//                $.throbberHide();
//            }

        }
    });
};
$.getInfo();
```

**PHP**

```
<?php



$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
include_once($root . '/assets/functions/db_dream.php');

$response = array();

$selected_reference_id = $_REQUEST['selected_reference_id'];

$DB = new DB();
$db = $DB->connect();

$stmt1 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM editors LEFT JOIN profile_videos pv ON editor_email = email WHERE reference_id = :reference_id ORDER BY pv.priority");
$stmt1->bindValue(':reference_id', $selected_reference_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt1->execute();
$results = $stmt1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($results as $row) {
    $details = array();
    $details["reference_id"] = $row['reference_id'];
    $details["email"] = $row['email'];
    $details["name"] = $row['name'];
    $details["profile_description"] = $row['profile_description'];
    $details["profile_image_url"] = $row['profile_image_url'];
    $details["video_url"] = $row['video_url'];
    $details["thumbnail_url"] = $row['thumbnail_url'];
    $details["editor_email"] = $row['editor_email'];
    $details["priority"] = $row['priority'];
    if($row['is_sports']){
        $details["is_sports"] = "<a class='button_custom small' style='margin-right: 5px' >EXTREME SPORTS</a>";
    }else{
        $details["is_sports"] = "";
    }
    if($row['is_weddings']){
        $details["is_weddings"] = "<a class='button_custom small' style='margin-right: 5px'>WEDDINGS</a>";
    }else{
        $details["is_weddings"] = "";
    }
    if($row['is_travel']){
        $details["is_travel"] = "<a class='button_custom small' style='margin-right: 5px'>TRAVEL</a>";
    }else{
        $details["is_travel"] = "";
    }
    if($row['is_everyday_moments']){
        $details["is_everyday_moments"] = "<a class='button_custom small' style='margin-right: 5px'>EVERYDAY MOMENTS</a>";
    }else{
        $details["is_everyday_moments"] = "";
    }
    if($row['is_special_occasions']){
        $details["is_special_occasions"] = "<a class='button_custom small' style='margin-right: 5px'>SPECIAL OCCASIONS</a>";
    }else{
        $details["is_special_occasions"] = "";
    }
    if($row['is_motion_graphics']){
        $details["is_motion_graphics"] = "<a class='button_custom small' style='margin-right: 5px'>MOTION GRAPHICS</a>";
    }else{
        $details["is_motion_graphics"] = "";
    }
    if($row['is_promo']){
        $details["is_promo"] = "<a class='button_custom small' style='margin-right: 5px'>PROMOS</a>";
    }else{
        $details["is_promo"] = "";
    }
    if($row['is_tutorials']){
        $details["is_tutorials"] = "<a class='button_custom small' style='margin-right: 5px'>TUTORIALS</a>";
    }else{
        $details["is_tutorials"] = "";
    }
    if($row['is_crowdfunding']){
        $details["is_crowdfunding"] = "<a class='button_custom small' style='margin-right: 5px'>CROWDFUNDING</a>";
    }else{
        $details["is_crowdfunding"] = "";
    }
    if($row['is_collage']){
        $details["is_collage"] = "<a class='button_custom small' style='margin-right: 5px'>PHOTO COLLAGE</a>";
    }else{
        $details["is_collage"] = "";
    }
    array_push($response, $details);
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: You say 'GET', but then your code says 'POST'.  Which is it?  This isn't a clear explanation of your issue.

Comment: I want to use GET paramater to create custom links .so create links like website.com/individual using GET parameter

Comment: what means "How can i create the links using GET parameter." and what type of problem you are facing ?

Comment: rana_sapient :my questions is how do i create custom links for individuals using their unique ids

Comment: Can you show us an exemple of what you want to generate ?

Comment: Alban : I want to create links like website.com/individual1.It would pull the data about individuals from their ids.

Comment: Ok but I don't see in your code where you get your user id's from. Furthemore, the example you just brought to me wasn't using GET. Ae you using url_rewriting or did you mean `website.com/?individual=1` ?

Comment: Alban : I meant website.com/?individual=1